# Vowel counting in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

So I'm trying to do a vowel counting but my code isn't working. Can someone help me pls?

```vb
    Dim nomes As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(" ")
    Dim primeiro As String = nomes(0)
    Dim segundo As String = nomes(1)
    Dim letras As String = nomes(0) + nomes(1)
    Dim consoantes As Integer = 0
    Dim vogals As Integer = 0
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(letras)
        If letras Like "[aeiou]" Then
            vogals = vogals + 1
        Else
            consoantes = consoantes + 1
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox("Tens " + vogals.ToString + " vogais  e " + consoantes.ToString + " consoantes")
End Sub
```

Comment: i think is my if statement i have tested to see if it was the letters counting and taking of the spaces between words

Comment: Apparently your `If letras` was meant to be `If letras(i)`.

Comment: i dont think so(anyways i tried)

Comment: Don't use Like, makes it hard to move to .netcore.  Favor `If "aeiou".IndexOf(letras(i)) >= 0 Then`.  And `For i = 0 To letras.Length-1`.  Or For Each.  Now it is vb.net code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could shorten that to:

```
Dim vogals, consoantes As Integer
For Each c As Char In TextBox1.Text
    If c Like "[aeiou]" Then
        vogals = vogals + 1
    ElseIf c Like "[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]" Then
        consoantes = consoantes + 1
    End If
Next
MessageBox.Show("Tens " + vogals.ToString + " vogais  e " + consoantes.ToString + " consoantes")
```

This will ignore the spaces and any other characters that are not vowels or consonants.

If you want to stick with the indexed for loop, then:

```
Dim vogals, consoantes As Integer
For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.TextLength - 1
    Dim c As String = TextBox1.Text(i)
    If c Like "[aeiou]" Then
        vogals = vogals + 1
    ElseIf c Like "[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]" Then
        consoantes = consoantes + 1
    End If
Next
MessageBox.Show("Tens " + vogals.ToString + " vogais  e " + consoantes.ToString + " consoantes")
```